# Continuous form of verb or Present participle?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, tenses, present-participles, present-continuous

Expanded version:

> Nobody likes to talk with the man **who is** sitting on the rock alone.

Reduced version:

> Nobody likes to talk with the man sitting on the rock alone.

How is it possible that in the expanded sentence, the word “sitting ” behaves as a continuous form of a verb and in the reduced sentence, the same word behaves as a present participle/adjective?

Comment: Better to look at the deletion as changing nothing, only removing the obvious.

Comment: "Nobody likes to talk to the man eating shark" vs "Nobody likes to talk to the man who is eating shark". No reason every word has to have the same function.

Comment: There is another possible “expansion” for *Nobody likes to talk with the man sitting on the rock alone.*: *Nobody likes to talk with the man who sits on the rock alone.*